# how to set the message attribute of the exception variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an Exception type variable in Ruby. How can I set the value of attribute "message" of the exception variable?
Is there any method to set the attribute (like rb_attr_set()..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for above question myself. We can set the "message" attribute of Exception object as follows:

```
rb_iv_set(*objeException, "mesg", current);
```

whereas current in VALUE type variable in which ruby string is stored..

Comment: What is `rb_iv_set`? Is it a Ruby documented method? Of which object? The message of an exception is set during the construction of the object: `my_exception = Exception.new "this is the message"`. There is no other way to set the message value.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos - The OP is writing a C extension.  `rb_iv_set` is one of the APIs available to a C extension.